# How can $\frac{x}{\pi}-\frac{n-x}{1-\pi}$ be the correct derivative of $x\log\pi+(n-x)\log(1-\pi)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, problem-solving

I am learning statistics and come across this calculation for Maximum-Likelihood estimator for the Binomial distribution. I don't understand the step from second to third row where they took the derivative,

[image: calculation]

my attempt gave me only $\log \left(π\right)$ as result. this is my calculation: 
$$\left(x \log \left(π\right)+\left(n-x\right)\log \left(1-π\right)\right)' = \\ = x'\log \left(π\right)+x\log \left(π\right)' + \left(n-x\right)'\log \left(1-π\right)+\left(n-x\right)\log \left(1-π\right)' = \\ \log \left(π\right) + 0 + 0 + 0 = \log \left(π\right)$$

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in this case, $\pi$ is the variable, not $x$

Comment: so $x'=0$ here ?

Comment: Yes, and $\pi'=1$. This is a problem with the prime notation.

Comment: yes. $x$ is treated as a constant.

Comment: so, is this special case, or should i take it always like this if the something like $\pi$ is a parameter of a function which i am taking derivative from?

Comment: You should always look inside the brackets (if there are some) to first see what the variable is, though admittedly this is a bit of an odd case

Comment: oh okay. thanks john, great help!. :)

Comment: no problem at all!

Comment: hey john, i am still coming to different solution with $\pi$ as variable. can you please help me

Comment: sure, what solution do you get?

Comment: $x/ \pi + log(1-\pi)$ somehow. i am treating x as constant

Comment: well the first term is correct, but how did you go about differentiating the second one? Remember, all of (n-x) is a constant now, but log(1-$\pi$) needs to be differentiated w.r.t. $\pi$

Comment: $log(1-\pi)'=\frac{1}{(1-\pi)}(1-\pi)'$ right? then $(1-\pi)'=-1$, oh yeah, sorry, i was confused :D

Comment: not quite. The log and the (1-$\pi$) aren't separate terms. Just like log($\pi$)'=1/$\pi$,   log(1+$\pi$)'=1/(1+$\pi$) and in this case log(1-$\pi$)=-1/(1-$\pi$) with the negative sign coming from the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative was done with respect to $\pi$ (a wrong choice of the parameter, indeed, as $\pi$ is a *standard constant*--a well known real number). Write $p$ instead of $\pi$ and differentiate with respect to $p$ to get the result.